# Creating good SEO friendly URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I have the following example URL:

```
http://mysite.com/tracks/backing-track?artist=abba&song=voulez+vous
```

**QUESTION:** Is this SEO friendly? Or would it be better:

```
http://mysite.com/tracks/backing-track/abba/voulez+vous
```

**QUESTION:** If the latter, is it possible to convert to this using `.htaccess` rules and if so, how?

I'm kind of new to SEO and using rewrites so looking to adopt best practice as early in the design stage as possible.

Comment: there is plenty of this type of questions on SO

Comment: Yes there are many, most don't say WHAT is friendly though - hence my first question.

Comment: Well, that's off-topic anyway: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes later URL scheme is better and friendly to SEO.

Here is .htaccess for 2nd scheme.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(tracks)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2?artist=$3&song=$4 [L,NC,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: Both are friendly to SEO - but not to SEO optimizer agents that want to get a buck. :)